# Make the cursor a hand when a user hovers over an icon?

Tags: angularjs

I add an icon to a node in a tree in Angular JS and I would like to make the cursor a hand when the mouse is over the icon.  I have the following definition in the html

```
<span class="key-icon glyphicon"
      ng-click="onClick()"
      ng-class="{ 'glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open': entryHasVorPADRights(entry), 'icon-cursor-change' : true } ">
</span>
```

and in the css I have the following:

```
  .icon-cursor-change {
    > .key-icon {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector doesn't seem correct to me. Both `.key-icon` and `.icon-cursor-change` are on the same element but you're using `>` for parent selector.

Try this instead:

`.icon-cursor-change.key-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}`